# How to fix this error: "Error in join expression. Can't parse query text"

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a complex SQL statement that I fall upon an error when I join this 'select' statement in. They prompted me this error:
`Error in Join expression. Can't parse query text.`

I pasted this SQL statement which I think causes this error. Can anyone advise me where went wrong? I never paste the whole SQL statement here as I think it would be messy for you guys to see, if you need, please tell me so. Any ideas???

```sql
SELECT        AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour1, Hour2, Hour3, Hour4, Hour5, Hour6, Hour7, Hour8, Hour9, Hour10, Hour11, Hour12, EmpName, ShiftTime, 
                     BreakTime, SignIn, SignOut
FROM            (SELECT        z.AllocationDate, z.LocationName, z.StationName, a.Hour1, b.Hour2, c.Hour3, d .Hour4, e.Hour5, f.Hour6, g.Hour7, h.Hour8, i.Hour9, j.Hour10, k.Hour11, 
                                                l.Hour12, m.EmpName, m.ShiftTime, m.BreakTime, m.SignIn, m.SignOut
                      FROM            (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName
                                                FROM            satsschema.viewmain
                                                WHERE        (StationName IS NOT NULL)) z LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour1
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view00000100) a ON z.LocationName = a.LocationName AND z.StationName = a.StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = a.AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour2
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view01000200) b ON z.LocationName = b.LocationName AND z.StationName = b.StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = b.AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour3
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view02000300) c ON z.LocationName = c.LocationName AND z.StationName = c.StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = c.AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour4
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view03000400) d ON z.LocationName = d .LocationName AND z.StationName = d .StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = d .AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour5
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view04000500) e ON z.LocationName = e.LocationName AND z.StationName = e.StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = e.AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour6
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view05000600) f ON z.LocationName = f.LocationName AND z.StationName = f.StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = f.AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour7
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view06000700) g ON z.LocationName = g.LocationName AND z.StationName = g.StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = g.AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour8
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view07000800) h ON z.LocationName = h.LocationName AND z.StationName = h.StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = h.AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour9
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view08000900) i ON z.LocationName = i.LocationName AND z.StationName = i.StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = i.AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour10
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view09001000) j ON z.LocationName = j.LocationName AND z.StationName = j.StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = j.AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour11
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view10001100) k ON z.LocationName = k.LocationName AND z.StationName = k.StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = k.AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, Hour12
                                                      FROM            satsschema.view11001200) l ON z.LocationName = l.LocationName AND z.StationName = l.StationName AND 
                                                z.AllocationDate = l.AllocationDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT        a.EmpName, CONCAT(b.StartTime, ' - ', b.EndTime) AS ShiftTime, CONCAT(a.EmpTime, ' - ', ADDTIME(a.EmpTime, '0 1:0:0.000000')) 
                                                                                AS BreakTime, a.Break, a.EmployeeOnBreak, '' AS SignIn, '' AS SignOut
                                                      FROM            satsschema.employeeslot a JOIN
                                                                                satsschema.ufis b m ON b.UFISID = a.UFISEmpGroup) Morning
                      WHERE        (AllocationDate = @AllocationDate) AND (LocationName = @LocationName) AND (StationName <> '') AND (Break = 1)
                      GROUP BY StationName, LocationName, AllocationDate
```

Comment: this snippet has unmatched parentheses, but I suspect that's because it's only part of the statement?  Does the query work in MySQL - removing whatever C# construct (ADO.NET? Entity Framework?) you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Your `ON` clause is outside the parenthesis `) m ON b.UFISID = a.UFISEmpGroup`, try this,

```
SELECT  a.EmpName, 
        CONCAT(b.StartTime, ' - ', b.EndTime) AS ShiftTime,
        CONCAT(a.EmpTime, ' - ', ADDTIME(a.EmpTime, '0 1:0:0.000000'))  AS BreakTime, 
        a.Break, 
        a.EmployeeOnBreak, 
        '' AS SignIn, 
        '' AS SignOut
FROM    satsschema.employeeslot a JOIN satsschema.ufis b m 
        ON b.UFISID = a.UFISEmpGroup
```

Comment: It prompt out the same error though. The error is it somewhere at other sql statement? This is only part of it. Should I paste the entire sql statement instead of this part?

Comment: much better if you can post the whole part.

Comment: Alright. I shall edit my post later. come back in a few mins.

Comment: I'm sorry but it a bit messy but there's the entire sql statement.

Comment: actually i'm still looking until now at your very long query :D